# Keyboard and mouse stay on after shutdown

Tags: mouse, power-management, keyboard-backlight

I'm having an annoying issue with my PC, the keyboard and mouse stay on after shutdown and this is odd because does not happen when I use Windows or put the computer to hibernate. It's completely annoying because every time I have to unplug both devices, since the keyboard have a bright backlight and the computer desk is in my bedroom.

To be more detailed: I'm also using a KVM switch to use the same keyboard and mouse on two computers and even when I remove the second's computer USB from the KVM switch, in which power is provided, the issue persists.

My OS is Xubuntu 20.04 by the way.

Comment: It might be possible to fix this in the bios. There's likely an option somewhere to allow USB devices to remain powered when the computer is turned of. If you can find this and turn off the setting, the problem should go away. As for why it's not happening in Windows. Windows generally has better support for advanced power management and newer (proprietory) device drivers.

Comment: The only option related to power management in the bios is Deep Sleep, enabling it solved the problem. Thank you!